# How to reload qml file to QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

what is the proper way of reloading qml file to QQuickView? I'm using Qt Quick 2.1 and trying to write a simple program that loads a qml file and displays it. Currently I'm doing it by creating a QQuickView and when i want to reload qml file i am deleting the old one and creating a new one. What is the proper way of doing this? calling QQuickView::setSource with new qml file (or changed qml file) didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following (assuming you are in a subclass of `QQuickView`):

```
QUrl tmp = source();
setSource(QUrl());
engine()->clearComponentCache();
setSource(tmp);
```

Comment: it worked. So it turns out that if you use setSource with a file you already use before, Qt uses it's cache mechanism and doesn't care about the changes you made inside qml file. if you want QQuickView to reload the qml file you need to clear the QQmlEngine cache. That's really helpful, Thanks a lot.

Comment: That engine function appears from the docs to clear *all* the cache in the entire Qt Quick interface, which could be a problem if all you want is to reload an individual QQuickView item. Does that sound right?

Comment: I'm using WebView at QML and wants to destroy all cookies and stored data. But engine()->clearComponentCache();
setSource(source()); doesn't help

Comment: I had to add `setSource(QUrl());` before clearing component cache, or the main QML would not get properly reloaded. I edited the answer to do this as well (feel free to roll back if you feel this is too invasive edit).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it his ways :

1. Create a main.qml (name can be anything) file, inside which, you will be actually loading and unloading other qml files.
2. Then use the [qml loader element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html) to load/unload (refresh if you may) any other file.

Comment: Actually i've tried this and it didn't work, Because of the QQmlEngine's cache mechanism it doesn't care about the changes i made inside qml file. To Solve this i need to clear the cache the way described in the previous answer.