# QML realtime programming

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I found a video which shows something which is called 'realtime programming' in the video.

This can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKGS5jEqivU#t=10m35s).

I think the idea is to edit QML files while the applications is running. As soon as changes are saved the application shows this changes immediately.

This eliminates the need of restarting the application to see the changes.

I think this is really great because it speeds up the work flow.

But I don't really get it how this works. What do I have to do to make something like this works on a Windows environment?

Comment: are we expected to watch the video to be able to reply?

Comment: If you know what I mean by this question without watching: Then no. To see what I mean you can watch from the posted timestamp about a minute or two. To get a better understanding you can watch the minutes before. If you don't want to watch it, don't watch it!

Comment: I think that it is called `C4 platform` but I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337493/how-to-reload-qml-file-to-qquickview/17352138#17352138) on how to reload a QML file:

```
engine()->clearComponentCache();
setSource(source());
```

Now all you need to do is hook that up to a `QFileSystemWatcher`. Make `QFileSystemWatcher` watch your QML file, and when it changes, reload the view.