# Reload qml in QQuickView source

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have test.qml file and in PyQt5 am using

```
self.view = QQuickView()
self.view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
self.view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'test.qml')))
```

I have a button when it is clicked it overwrite the test.qml and call view again to read the test.qml file but it still display the old test.qml not the new one. Why?

Is it something with QQmlEngine clearComponentCache()

sample of the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
import  os

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def add(self):
        # call a function in a nother python file that will open test.qml and overwite it 
        # when i call the test.qml again it will show the old version not the new one 
        self.view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'root.qml'))) 

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 380, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 50, 551, 311))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)

        # loading the qml for the first time
        self.view = QQuickView()
        self.view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
        self.view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'root.qml')))
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(self.view)
        vbox.addWidget(self.widget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: the qml is a normal qml file i did not add anything to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with QQuickView yet but rather prefer QQmlApplicationEngine. With it, I used an approach similar to the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17352138/6367098).

I guess you could add a method like this to your main window class:

```
def reload(self):
    self.view.engine().clearComponentCache()
    self.view.setSource(
        QUrl.fromLocalFile(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'root.qml')))
```

The `clearComponentCache()` method causes the engine to discard any previously loaded QML documents. On the next load operation (e.g. by using `setSource()` on your view), the engine will hence be force to reload the file from disk.